# Parameterizing intersection curve of paraboloids

Tags: parametrization, stokes-theorem, intersection-theory

I'm at a loss for ideas on what to do.
I'm given two paraboloids and their equations:
$z_1 = x^2 + 1$ and $z_2 = 5 - y^2$.

I know their intersection is when $z_1 = z_2$.

This gives me $x^2 + y^2 = 4$, the equation of a circle. Which makes sense, because the projection of the intersection on the xy plane is a circle.

With this, I could parameterize with $x(\theta) = 2\cos \theta $ and $y(\theta) = 2 \sin \theta$, using polar coordinates.

My questions begin here, is $z(t) = 0$? Practically, it doesn't make sense because the intersection of the curves go up and down the $z$ axis, but I don't understand what else it could be, if not just $z$ ranging from $z_2 = 5 - y^2$ to $z_1 = x^2 + 1$.

In either case, my next question, is regarding calculating closed curve integral of a vector field $\overrightarrow{F}$ around this intersection. My problem with this, is that to find the normal vector $\overrightarrow{n}$ from $\int\int_S \nabla \times \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \overrightarrow{n} dS$, I need to calculate the cross product of the partial derivatives of my parametrized intersection equation.

Suppose that I use $z(z) = z$, then my parametrized equation is $R(\theta, z) = 2\cos \theta \overrightarrow{i} + 2\sin \theta\overrightarrow{j} + z \overrightarrow{k}$.
I'll spare you the details, but ultimately I'm left evaluating an intergral with a cosine and sine ranging from $0$ to $2\pi$, which leaves me with a big ZERO. I'm sure there is something wrong somewhere, and I cannot figure out what.

**Hints** on potential solution tracks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you used geogebra to try to sketch out the shape? Moreover, it seems quite natural that $z(\theta)\ne0$. And can you try to use some formula in this question relate $z$ to $x$, so that $x$ is related to $\theta$, and you can relate $z$ with $\theta$?

Comment: I did, and I found the right equation with z = 4cos^2(theta) + 1 and I checked with geogebra that it works. But finding the normal vector remains problematic because putting x, y and z together gives me a function with only one variable.

Comment: I JUST got it, I think, by taking u = cos(t) and v = sin(t) and making a new parametrized equation

Comment: The curve $\langle x^2+w^2-zw, 5w^2-y^2-zw\rangle$  is rational, the singular point is $(x:y:z:w)=(0:0:1:0).$ In $w=1$ using the radius $2$ circle parametrization $(2(t^2-1)/(1+t^2):2(2t/(1-t^2)):(5 t^4 - 6 t^2 + 5)/(t^2 + 1)^2:1)$ which works since $(0:2:1:1)$ is on the curve (we can't use $1-t^2$), we get $(x:y:z:w)=(2(t^2-s^2)(t^2 + s^2):2(2st)(t^2 + s^2):(5 t^4 - 6 t^2s^2 + 5s^4):(t^2 + s^2)^2).$